# Can't figure out what's wrong with my method

Tags: python

I have a list/dictionary that stores a word corresponding with a number like so:

```
MSG1        3027
MEMORYSPACE 3036
NEWLINE     3037
NEG48       3038
```

My method retrieves a number if the user enter the word:

```
def retrieve_data():
    insert_data()
    nb = input('Choose a label: ')
    for j in data:
        a=j[0]
        b=j[1]
        if a == nb:
            print(b)
        else:
            print('Label not in list!')
```

so i should just get 3036 but this is the output i get when i call the method:

```
Choose a label: MEMORYSPACE
Label not in list!
3036
Label not in list!
Label not in list!
```

any idea why it's doing this? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you loop over each item of the dict and only one matches so it prints out `Label not in list!` for the others. You want to remove one indent level from else and break after print(b)

```
def retrieve_data():
    insert_data()
    nb = input('Choose a label: ')
    for j in data:
        a=j[0]
        b=j[1]
        if a == nb:
            print(b)
            break
    else:
        print('Label not in list!')
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looping over every entry in data, so it's printing for every item in data. This problem is perfect for a dictionary:

```
data = {'MSG1': 3027, 'MEMORYSPACE': 3036, 'NEWLINE': 3037, 'NEG48': 3038}
nb = input('Choose a label: ')
print(data.get(nb, 'Label not in list!'))
```

(Edited as per comment below, if you still want it to print "not in list")

Comment: Just a minor improvement here: `print(data.get(nb, 'Label not in list!'))`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to do this is

```
dic={"MSG1":3027,"MEMORYSPACE":3036,"NEWLINE":3037,"NEG48":3038}


def retrieve_data():
    nb=raw_input("Choose a label: ")

    if nb in dic.keys():
        print dic[nb]
    else:
        print "Label not in list!"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doping it because in every cicle of the the foorloop you call an if/else statement that will print ether one thing or another. And in only one circle you can get the 'right' answer.

There are better ways to do what you want, but I'll try to write a code as clos e as possible to yours:

```
def retrieve_data():
    found = False
    insert_data()
    nb = input('Choose a label: ')
    for j in data:
        a=j[0]
        b=j[1]
        if a == nb:
            found = True
            print(b)
    if not found:
        print('Label not in list!')
```

Or

```
def retrieve_data():
    insert_data()
    nb = input('Choose a label: ')
    i = 0
    while i < range(len(data)):
        j = data[i]
        a=j[0]
        b=j[1]
        if a == nb:
            print(b)
            break
        i += 1
else:
    print('Label not in list!')
```